# Change text color of first row in Powershell Table

Tags: powershell

How can I change the color of the text in the first row of a powershell table?

I've seen this

```
@{"Bob"=1;"John"=3;} | Format-Table @{
    Label = "Name"
    Expression =
    {
        if ("John" -eq $_.Name)
        {
            $color = "32" #green
        }
        else
        {
            $color = "0" #white
        }
        $e = [char]27
        "$e[${color}m$($_.Name)${e}[0m"
    }
}, Value
```

But I am not sure how to adapt it without a conditional. I want the first row of the table to be printed green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using ANSI escape codes, You could do this:

```
switch -Regex ((@{"Bob"=1;"John"=3} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String) -split '\r?\n' ) {
    '^John'  { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green }
    default  { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor White }
}
```

[image]

---

If your intention is to always write out the **first data line** in a different color, you can do

```
$lines = (@{"Bob"=1;"John"=3} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Trim() -split '\r?\n'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i++) {
    $color = if ($i -eq 2) { 'Green' } else { 'White' }
    Write-Host $lines[$i] -ForegroundColor $color
}
```

Comment: And say I don't know the first row's value?

Comment: Except for having to change the index `($i -eq 0)` this works!